# Prometheus statefulset is not created after deploying prometheus operator with kubernetes stack

Tags: monitoring, prometheus, prometheus-operator, kubernetes-statefulset, thanos

I have deployed prometheus operator on k8s cluster.Kubernetes stack is also deployed along with it.All the CRD files created but prometheus statefulset is not created (prometheus-k8s-0 is not created).

Comment: Your question is off-topic in StackOverflow. You have a better chance to get it answered if you move it to [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) or to [Superuser](https://superuser.com).

Comment: @Usama Can you add some error logs or the operator logs? Or prometheus configuration?

Comment: If you're using EKS on Fargate then that would be expected. You'd need to make sure that you're using deploy not STS and disable persistent volumes.

Comment: @rohatgisanat operator  showing 
level=error ts=2021-05-18T03:48:10.863557044Z caller=klog.go:116 component=k8s_client_runtime func=ErrorDepth msg="pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.21.0/tools/cache/reflector.go:167: Failed to watch *v1.Probe: failed to list *v1.Probe: probes.monitoring.coreos.com is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:thanos:prometheus-operator\" cannot list resource \"probes\" in API group \"monitoring.coreos.com\" at the cluster scope"

Comment: Now showing
level=info ts=2021-05-18T04:23:25.352498897Z caller=operator.go:1236 component=prometheusoperator msg="resolving illegal update of Prometheus StatefulSet" details="&StatusDetails{Name:prometheus-k8s,Group:apps,Kind:StatefulSet,Causes:[]StatusCause{StatusCause{Type:FieldValueForbidden,Message:Forbidden: updates to statefulset spec for fields other than 'replicas', 'template', and 'updateStrategy' are forbidden,Field:spec,},},RetryAfterSeconds:0,UID:,}"

Comment: @UsamaMalick For errors and logs. Please attach a screenshot to the question.
It seems you have made an illegal edit to the prometheus statefulset as shown in the last error. Please undo the last change and try deploying again.